# Java - Making a database login system

Tags: java, mysql

I have a very basic login application atm. I would like it to connect to Mysql Database and get the login details from there. This code i am using atm has to connect to the login server to login. This allows me to stop people from logging in when there the application is undergoing maintance.

How would i go about making my application connect to my database and receive the user/pass.

Here is the code

```
 public void actionnlogin(){
        blogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        String puname = txuser.getText();
        String ppaswd = pass.getText();
        if(puname.equals("123") && ppaswd.equals("123") || (puname.equals("123") && ppaswd.equals("123"))) {
            try 
            {

                Socket s = new Socket(HOST, PORT);

                System.out.println("You connected to " + Settings.Settings.NAME);//gets name of product from settings page

                LoginClient client = new LoginClient(s);

                Thread t = new Thread(client);
                t.start();
                HomePage regFace =new HomePage();
                regFace.setVisible(true);
                dispose();

            } 
            catch (Exception noServer)
            {
            if (Settings.Settings.UNDER_MAINTANCE) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,Settings.Settings.MAINTANCEMESSAGE);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,Settings.Settings.Unavilable);
            }
            }
        } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Username/Password, please retry.",
        "Invalid Username/Password",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        txuser.setText("");
        pass.setText("");
        txuser.requestFocus();

        }
        }

        });
        }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i would like to know how to get username and passwords from a mysql database for a login system

Comment: Google for "JDBC tutorial" and read.